# install libssh2.dll on windows

Tags: windows, dll, libssh2

I want to install SSH on my PC (windows 7 64bits). 
But I have a problem with the installation of libssh2.dll file 
I saved in: C: \ Windows \ SysWOW64 
and even in C: \ Windows \ System32 
and when I execute this command "regsvr32 libssh2.dll" in cmd as administrator I get this error message: 
Libssh2.dll "The module" "was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.

Verify that "libssh2.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and try again. "

I downloaded from this site file: 
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/ 
The only good that contains the libssh2.dll is x86 (knowing that I have a 64bits), is what may be causing the problem? 
If someone knows a solution, please, share it, it is very important that I find a solution as soon as possible and thank you.

Comment: What you have downloaded is not a COM component, it is a .dll file. No need to register.

Comment: Hi , what do you mean by COM component ?

Comment: COM = "Component Object Model". It is the kind of element accesible via `CreateObject("ProgID")`, `new ActiveXObject("ProgID")`, `new COM("ProgID")`, `CoCreateInstance(...` or whatever other construct depending of the language. A COM .dll file needs (usually) to be registered, but a "standard" .dll file can not be registered as a component, the task regsvr32 is designed to do. What you have downloaded is a PHP pecl extension, a "standard" .dll designed to be included in the adecuated folder to be dynamic loaded when required (in this case usually by php engine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put that libssh2.dll somewhere on the %path% so then the PHP extension can find it. Logic were to put it into your PHP dir (if you use the standard zipball from windows.php.net).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me

Answer (score -1):

well why have you downloaded a 32 bit file to a 64 bit system
am I missing something here
You can only run a 32bit type if your Apache PHP and MySQL have 32bit running versions or 64 bit in your case. So if you are running a 32bit OS on a 64bit system then this is fine, if you are running 64 bit script on a 64 bit system and are trying to use a 32 bit script which I suspect you are then this is not fine!

I would therefore suggest that if this is the case you may have a mix match of OS Versus Script.

There are a few brave people operating in the 64 bit world and you should only ever use the stable versions of the product and like Apache unless you do you will not get the support you want because you have not utilised a stable version only and Apache will not support 64 bit, hence Apache lounge.

If you are running off localhost or 127.0.0.1, then running a stable 32 bit OS and running the 32 bit stable version is the only way you will get support.